# What does "ReactComponentTreeDevtool: Missing React element for debugID 9 when building stack" mean?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, sinon, enzyme

I am trying to test a React component with mocha, enzyme and sinon and am getting the following error. Does anyone know what it means?

> Warning: ReactComponentTreeDevtool: Missing React element for debugID 9 when building stack

The code is large and I'm having trouble coming up with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. It appears to be caused by the order of the tests I'm running. Does anyone have any information about the kind of things that might cause this issue and things I should check for to enable me to pin things down a little further.

Comment: Which version of React? 15.3.0 had some issues that caused this warning, they were solved with 15.3.1.

Comment: Yes that seems to have solved it. If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React v15.3.0 (and possibly versions before it) had a bug that would cause this warning (see issues [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7187) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7240)).

According to the comments, this should be solved with React v15.3.1.